# QRadioButton not Resetting to unchecked

Tags: c++, qt

I have an `QDialog` class say '*OptionsClass*' to display a dialog for options for my Application.
I have designed it in *Qt Designer* & the object of that class is created in the `constructor` of my `QMainWindow` inherited class by `new` & it is `delete`d in the `destructor` (I think this helps in quickly loading the Dialog when button is clicked). Whenever the options button is clicked I am calling a function in `OptionsClass` which basically edits some text in `QLabel` & after that calling `show`(). There are 3 `QRadioButton`'s also in the `QDialog` class.
When I open the dialog for the 1st time in my application's startup the radio button's are unchecked. Now say i check any button & close the dialog. Now if I again open the Dialog then still that radio button is checked. I want that everytime I open the Dialog all the radio button's should be unchecked.

Here's the SLOT for the button which is clicked to open the Dialog:

```
void MyMainWindow::on_actionCut_triggered()
{
    optionsObj->init(n, 'x');
    optioobjn->show();
}
```

Here is a snippet of the function init:

```
void OptionsClass::init(int n, char c)
{
    //some settings to edit the QLabel
    ui->radio1->setChecked(false);
    ui->radio2->setChecked(false);
    ui->radio3->setChecked(false);
}
```

I have tried with other properties like SetDown(), SetChecked(), etc but still it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent your button from resetting, you need to do

```
radio-> setAutoExclusive(false);
```

Then you can uncheck. Don't forget to turn autoExclusive on again.

AutoExclusive is normally off for other abstract buttons, [but on for Radio buttons.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#autoExclusive-prop)